# iOS dynamic object creation and storage

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

What I have is a UIButton. What I want to do is, every time the button is clicked, a new UIImageView is created (I will set the size/image etc... in a method) and the UIImageView falls to the bottom of the screen. How do I do this? I've tried creating the object and storing it in an NSMutableArray and doing a for loop on the array but that doesn't seem to work. (example of what I'm doing)

```
-(IBAction) button {
   [self createUiImage];
}
-(void) createUiImage {
   UIIMageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 15, 3)]
   iv.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
   iv.hidden = NO;
   [self.view addSubview:iv];
   [array1 addObject:iv];
}
-(void) dropImageDown {
    for (UIImageView *a in array1) {
        a.center = CGPointMake(a.center.x, a.center.y + 10);
        if (a.center.y > 500) {
            [array1 removeAllObjects];
            [a removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
}
```

and this dropImageDown method is being controlled by an NSTimer.

***forgot to add this: The problem is that the shape isn't falling to the bottom, it appears and doesn't move!***

I've also tried a `for (int i = 0; i < array size; i ++)` but thats not working either
Appreciate the help, thanks

Comment: You're adding `bullet` to `array1` rather than adding your new imageView (iv)

Comment: sorry ignore that, its supposed to be iv

Comment: Inside of your if statement, you have `[array1 removeAllObjects];`. I don't think you want to drop the entire array; only the one that has a center.y > 500.

Comment: yea you're right again! but I'm just testing for one object right now :) :) :) bear with me lol (in other words i'm only clicking the button once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason I was having issues... I was not initializing the NSMutableArray therefore it wasn't being recognized.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to use a timer and move the view in steps yourself. It will give jerky animation that puts a large burden on the CPU.

Use UIView animation instead.

Something like this:

```
-(void) animateImagesDown {
    for (UIImageView *a in array1) 
    {
      [UIView animateWithDuration: 1.0
      animations: ^
      {
        a.center = CGPointMake(a.center.x, 500);
      }
      completion: ^(BOOL finished) 
      {
        [a removeFromSuperview];
      }
      ];
    }
}
```

That code would animate all the view to a center position of 500, then remove them. (They would all be animated at the same time.)

UIView animations use ease-in, ease-out animation by default. There are other variations on the animateWithDuration UIView animation methods that let you control the animation timing. (look at the docs on the `methodanimateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`(Specifically the options parameter.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however this didn't work. The object is created, but it isn't moving, which is the same issue I was having. The objects are being created but they are not moving. I have a feeling it's because they are stored in an array...

Comment: so let me ask you, am I doing the object creation and storage correctly? (excuse my terminology, I learned Java first so I'm more familiar with that) Is it screwing something up when I'm storing the object reference in an array after creating it? is that why it isn't moving after it's created?

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems with the way you are creating your image views. You posted a method that creates a single image view. Are you calling that method in a loop from aother method? When is it being called? Are you sure you're creating the views before trying to animate them?

Comment: Another thing that seems odd: your image views are only 3 points tall. Do they contain thin horizontal lines? Anything else would be too short to be drawn correctly.

Comment: I'm calling the method when the button is clicked (notice in my code the button method is calling [self createUiImage]). Let me double check something and get back to you, thank you for all the help by the way, I appreciate it.

Comment: yea so the object is definitely created before i try to animate it.. not sure why its not moving.

Comment: any ideas?? Still haven't found an answer

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html use this link which can be help to understand the concept

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response, however this link doesn't really help with my specific problem